# Iterating through directories and infinite sub-directories

Tags: java, iteration

I have a program where you can add a full array of subjects, then within each of those, a full array of subjects, and so on forever. I am making a loader for said program, to load pre-made Subject maps. I have a base subject, two sub-subjects, and 1 subject in each sub-subject. My code works for 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2, but not 1.2.1. Can you take a look?

```
private static Subject search(String title, ArrayList<Subject> subList) {

    for (Subject sub : subList) {

        if (sub.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return sub;
        } else {
            return search(title, sub.getSubs());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

From what I can tell, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: On obvious problem is that your code always returns from the if statement, so you only look at the first element of subList.

Comment: just change `return search(title,sub.getSubs())` to `search(title,sub.getSubs())`

Comment: Now it is failing to add 1.1.1 and 1.2.1

Comment: Try setting `Subject s = search(title, sub.getSubs());` and do `if (s != null) return s;` after it.